# Cannot change Cassandra datacenter

Tags: cassandra

After cassandra install via `sudo apt install -y cassandra`, cassandra is running, but I have not yet configured `cassandra.yaml` and `cassandra-topology.properties`. Once I configure them cassandra won't start because `Cannot start node if snitch's data center (0) differs from previous data center (datacenter1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you don't care about the data stored, you can fix that by deleting everything in your `data_file_directories`.  If you're not setting that, you'll find it at `$CASSANDRA_HOME/data/data`.

Basically, the cluster metadata gets written in the `system` keyspace, which uses the local replication strategy (`system` is unique on each node).  At start time, Cassandra verifies the stored metadata vs. the config properties being passed.  When you change something about the node, Cassandra will throw an error on specific properties like `cluster_name`, `dc`, `rack` (and possibly a few others) when they don't match what's on disk.

**tl;dr;**

You probably only need to delete only the data for the `system` keyspace.

But another option, would be to uncomment and set `data_file_directories`. Then the new node's system metadata would be written there, and the node would start.